# SQL Server 2008 Cannot open user default database - error 4064

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database application which has been working fine in the past, but since restoring my server a few weeks ago the main user login has stopped working -
 I get this error when I try to login from SSMS. 
The default database is defined correctly for the user in question, and I can connect to (and query) that database using the sa user. The database is online, set to MULTI_USER, isn't set to emergency status, and isn't part of a database mirror. The user that is being denied access is not a member of a group, and I've confirmed that the default database is set correctly for that user. If I can connect to the database in question using the sa user then clearly there's a problem with my chosen user/login, but I've run out of ideas. Can anyone help?
I'm running SQL Server 2008 on a Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error message

Comment: Is this database a backup from the same machine or did it come from another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this error in following cases:

- database does not exist
- database cannot be open (is offline, is restoring, etc)
- your login is not mapped to the database

If you are sure that database exists and is online, you `user` can be orphaned.
This means that the login's `sid` does not correspond to user's `sid`, this could be caused by restore.

You can fix tihis by altering your user with login:

```
alter user MyUser with login = MyLogin
```

Comment: Many thanks - it looks as if the user was orphaned, and your solution worked perfectly!